WPF, .NET. PropertyChanged Event does not trigger UI Update as a callback of DispatcherTimer
The original goal for each Timer Tick is to call a method that would take the current coordinates of the analog buttons (and the pressed button) of the joystick. (I use SharpDX.XInput)
In this example I'm just trying to show the current time
UI correctly shows the value set from the constructor CurrentTime = “Test”;
Then in the console every second shows the correct time, as well as the CurrentTime property changes value.
OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentTime)) for some reason does not trigger UI update. Hence the UI shows “test”.
I have tried different timers, including System.Threading.Timer
This DispatcherTimer seems to be the most suitable since it is executed on the same thread as the UI.
public class ControlInfoViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private JoystickService _joystickService;
    private DispatcherTimer _timer;

    public ControlInfoViewModel(JoystickService joystickService)
    {
        _joystickService = joystickService;
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000) };
        _timer.Tick += UpdateTime;
        _timer.Start();
        CurrentTime = "Test";
        
    }
    
    
    private string _currentTime {  get; set; }
    public string CurrentTime
    {
        get => _currentTime;
        set
        {
            _currentTime = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentTime));
        }
    }
    public void UpdateTime(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int uiThreadId = Application.Current.Dispatcher.Thread.ManagedThreadId;
        int currentThreadId = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

        if (uiThreadId == currentThreadId)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("TimerTick is on the UI thread.");   // <---- this 
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("TimerTick is NOT on the UI thread.");
        }

        CurrentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(CurrentTime);
    }

public class ViewModelBase
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public virtual void Dispose() { }

}

My view:
<UserControl x:Class="Underwater_WPF.View.ControlInfoView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Underwater_WPF.View"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Underwater_WPF.ViewModel"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodel:ControlInfoViewModel}"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding CurrentTime, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="102" Margin="151,242,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="334"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>

However, the implementation from View.cs class works just fine, as in the example from: https://wpf-tutorial.com/misc/dispatchertimer/

Where do you set DataContext? I expect to see some binding errors. d:xxx properties are only used at design time.

ViewModelBase should have base interface INotifyPropertyChanged.

Also note that setting UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on the Text Binding is pointless. Despite the name, it has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

And why is there public virtual void Dispose() { } in ViewModelBase? It seems entirely useless.
